# Reformat a DECIMAL value from Model throughout the views in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am wondering if it is possible to reformat a DECIMAL value from the model throughout the views. Let me explain... In the database I have a value DECIMAL(2,1). In most cases the values will be 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 and so on... But very rarely it can be 2.5... Now I want it to always be shown rounded down to 1, 2, 3 unless it's not a .0 number.

I do not want to this in all the views, as I believe this is a way overkill thing to instead of doing it from the model.

Anybody any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a accessor in your model so that whenever that variable is needed, it will format it in a certain way.

That is done by adding a new function to the model which would be the column name in your database in snakeCase with the word `get` prefixed and the word `Attribute` suffixed.  For example, if your column name was `some_decimal`, you'd add a function `getSomeDecimalAttribute()` to your model.

With that said, yours would look something like this...

```
public function getSomeDecimalAttribute()
{
    $num = $this->attributes['some_decimal'];

    $pos = strpos($num, '.');

    if($pos === false) { // it is integer number
        return $num;
    } else { // it is decimal number
        return rtrim(rtrim($num, '0'), '.');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an [accessor](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators). If your field name is "amount", you would do:

```
public function getAmountAttribute($value)
{
    return number_format(floor($value), 2);
}
```

And just substitute the logic you care about in there. Wasn't totally sure what you meant.